# How are function signature hashes calculated in serpent?

Tags: solidity, serpent

We know in solidity it is something like this bytes4(keccak256("hello(string)") but what about serpent? In Theory we should be able to call serpent contract code from solidity using these signature hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it is the same as in solidity despite the variables being named differently.

Example is here for BTCRelay: https://github.com/James-Sangalli/btcrelay/blob/gh-pages/examples/BitcoinRelayABI.js